# How to send NSData on server through Post request using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking, nsdata

I want to send data on server using `AFNetworking`. I want to send `NSData` not json parameter. Can anyone suggest how can I send `NSData` on server using `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                      parameters:(id)parameters
       constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

The way that you would use the method is:

```
[self POST:@"http://myurl.com" parameters:@{} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    // attach the NSData to `formData`
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    // Handle Success
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    // Handle Error
}];
```

In order to attach the data you could use this method in the `AFMultipartFormData` protocol

```
- (void)appendPartWithFormData:(NSData *)data
                          name:(NSString *)name;
```